# Integrating Helpstack on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Helpstack was running correctly on eclipse but when we move to android studio, Helpstack can't get any articles or submit any issues, it seems it can't access internet.

We have imported helpstack as a module in andriod studio and then we compile help stack by using

`**compile project(":helpstack")**`

in build.gradle.
Screenshot :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwyd22zyoK5yeEZ6aWxWSGozSEJBNU9UbGJoX2hrMUt6bVdR/view?usp=sharing